# Fazer um jogo continuar ou parar conforme escolha do jogador

Tags: c, algoritmo, while

Nesse jogo o jogador escolhe um numero limite e a partir desse limite será sorteado um número e o usuário precisa acertá-lo, estou fazendo com função, porém não sei como a chamo novamente caso o usuário deseje jogar novamente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int aleatorio(int niv){
int aleat,tent,res;
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));//gera um numero aleatorio novo,o unsigned serve para gerar um valor positivo
aleat=(rand() % niv)+1;
while(aleat!=tent){
    printf("%d\n",aleat);
    printf("Digite o numero secreto");
    scanf("%d",&tent);
    system("cls");

}
printf("parabéns voce acertou!!\n");
printf("Digite 1 para jogar novamente ou qualquer tecla para sair");
scanf("%d",&res);
if(res==1){
    aleatorio();
}



}

int main()
{
    int niv,res;
    printf("Digite o numero limite");
    scanf("%d",&niv);

    aleatorio(niv);
    printf("Deseja jogar novamente?");
    scanf("%d",&res);



    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem diversos problemas neste código. Primeiro, eu não usaria uma função para isto, não parece que precisa, não tem um motivo claro para usar, se não existe motivo não use. Se for pra usar função faça em algo que encapsule uma lógica específica. Claro que pode, mas parece um uso artificial. Quase sempre se vai usar apenas uma vez não faz muito sentido criar a função, a não ser que algo seja grande demais ou que tenha uma lógica clara separada. No caso acho que a lógica está esquisita e pelo menos eu tentei deixar mais correto pensando que acertar o aleatório é uma lógica e tentar outro número é outra lógica, feito assim até que a função faz algum sentido.

Eu separei a inicialização da semente porque na forma que está fazendo é desnecessária é quase errada, no caso até funciona porque inicializa com o tempo, mas semente se inicializa uma vez por aplicação. e o comentário usado dá uma indicação do errado do que a função faz, ela não gera número algum, quem gera é a `rand()`.

Tirei a parte que imprime o número sorteado porque não faz sentido um jogo de adivinhação mostrar o número a ser adivinhado.

Mudei o texto para deixar mais claro como encerrar o jogo. O texto do acerto ainda parece esquisito porque a pessoa vai acertar, ou ela nem consegue sair do jogo, mas enfim, isso é algo que deveria ser melhorado.

Se a função não retorna nada então o tipo dela deve ser `void()`.

Inicializei `tent` porque pode em algum caso nem entrar no laço por causa disto.

E claro eliminei repetição de código nas duas funções deixando a lógica da repetição só em uma, de forma correta.

Eliminei coisas desnecessárias e escrevi o código de um jeito mais organizado. Outras coisas podem ser melhoradas nisto.

Como exercício dê melhores nomes para as variável, principalmente sem abreviar, deixe legível, não tenha preguiça de ditar o nome todo. Se quer digitar menos pare de por coisas que não são necessárias no código e digitará menos mantendo a legibilidade.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

void aleatorio(int niv) {
    int aleat = (rand() % niv) + 1;
    int tent = -1;
    while (aleat != tent) {
        printf("Digite o numero secreto");
        scanf("%d", &tent);
    }
    printf("parabéns voce acertou!!\n");
}

int main() {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int niv, res = -1;
    printf("Digite o numero limite: ");
    scanf("%d", &niv);
    while (res != 0) {
        aleatorio(niv);
        printf("Deseja jogar novamente? (0 - Não 1 - Sim)");
        scanf("%d", &res);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/28C4r6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/RepeatConcernc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/RepaeatConcern.c).

Comment: Obrigado,entendi a explicação,sobre o numero secreto está printando era para facilitar os testes.Obrigado mais uma vez.

Answer (score 0):

Algo assim resolveria:

```
int main() {

    int niv, opcao;

    do {

        printf("Digite o numero limite: ");
        scanf("%d", &niv);

        aleatorio(niv);

        printf("Deseja jogar novamente? [s/n]: ");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);

    } while (opcao != 'n');

    return 0;
}
```